# Remove text from file after only a specific match

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file with multiple occurances of a string, I need to remove only one of the occurrences using a specific match. I cannot seem to get a good way of doing this, i keep removing all occurrences

```
sed -i "s/|item2//g"
```

file format:

```
 "1234567890|item2",
 "1234567895|item2",
 "3454343345|item1|item2",
 "7854343345|item1|item3",
 "0454343555|item1|item4|item6",
```

What i need to do is to match the first set of numbers say 3454343345 then after this remove a specific string, like item2.

Output I am trying to get

```
 "1234567890|item2",
 "1234567895|item2",
 "3454343345|item1|",
 "7854343345|item1|item3",
 "0454343555|item1|item4|item6",
```

Comment: You say you want to _match with the numbers_, then why don't you use the numbers for matching? What should the output look like?

Comment: Yes i tried to pipe using grep, this infact does what i want in the output but i need to do this as a file edit not stdout

grep -w "3454343345" file | sed -i "s/|pattern//g" 

output: 

         "3454343345|pattern2",

Comment: just remove the 'g' from your `sed` command ....

Comment: Are your lines quoted like that?

Comment: yes, that is how it is in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 sed -e '/^"3454343345/ s/item2//' file

"1234567890|item2",
"1234567895|item2",
"3454343345|item1|",
"7854343345|item1|item3",
"0454343555|item1|item4|item6",
```

- Replace `-e` with `-i` to edit inline, if the output matches your desired result.

Comment: If the placeholder `item1` (for example) happens to be the same as the string `3454343345`, this would remove the wrong things. You should anchor the pattern to the start of the line. Also, note that this will remove `item2` as a substring from anywhere on the line (e.g. from `theitem22`).  Also, again, while "trying" a `sed` command, _never_ use `-i`. Doing so would mess up the data if the command happens to be wrong.

Comment: @Kusalananda ur right....